# Does CoreTelephony framework works in JailBreak device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak, core-telephony

I have used coretelephony framework in my application. It worked when I test my application in non-jailbreak device.

Today when I asked my client to test the app, it didn't work for him and he is using a jailbreak device.

What I should do to work my application even in Jailbreak device?

Comment: You would need to post the specific code you're using for us to help you.  Just telling us that it's something in CoreTelephony isn't enough information.  In general, your CoreTelephony code should work just fine on a jailbroken device.

Comment: @Nate I have edited my post. Can you look into it.

Comment: We still can't run that code.  You don't give us the value (or the code needed to assign the value) of `mach_port` or `conn`, or `a`.

Comment: @Nate Updated the code again. Can you check now.

Comment: Not yet.  You don't show what `ConnectionCallback` is.  Do you see the pattern here?  If you want people to help debug code, especially if it's using little-used private APIs as you are, you need to provide a runnable sample.

Comment: @Nate I have uploaded code in github. Here is the link: https://github.com/Deepthi-Taduvayi/iPhoneAgent

Answer (score 1):

coretelephony framework works well on Jailbroken devices

Comment: I have uploaded the project in github. Here is the link: github.com/Deepthi-Taduvayi/iPhoneAgent . Can you check this once.